# Windows CE emulator on visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2005, windows-ce

I've installed visual studio 2005 and windows embedded c.e. 6.0. 
How do I create a simple `hello world` program in visual studio and then port it to a Win C.E. emulator and run the same there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does [this page](http://www.wirelessdevnet.com/channels/pda/training/vcce.html) help?

Quoted from there:

> Your First Visual C++ for Windows CE
>   Application
>
> Your first Visual C++ for Windows CE
>   application will be a simple
>   application, a WCE MFC AppWizard (EXE)
>   to be precise. This application will
>   have a single view that will have a
>   bitmap painted on it. We will also add
>   a menu item that when clicked will
>   evoke a dialog. This dialog will
>   contain one of the Windows Common
>   Controls, a progress control. Creating
>   the Basic Application
>
> Download the sample application source
>   code.
>
> To start your first Windows CE
>   application we will generate a shell
>   using the WCE MFC AppWizard. The
>   numbered list below will step you
>   trough this process:
>   1. Open Visual C++ and go to the File menu and choose the New item
>   2. Select the Projects property tab if it is not already selected.
>   3. Select WCE MFC AppWizard (exe) in the list control.
>   4. Type WCEFirstApp in the Project name edit box
>
> When you finish, you will see the New
>   dialog box as seen in Figure 3.
>
> 5. Press the Next button.
>
> WCE MFC AppWizard (exe) - Step 1 of 4
>   will appear as seen in Figure 4.
>   Notice that the selections are similar
>   to the MFC AppWizard except that there
>   is no Multiple documents selection.
>   6. Accept the defaults.
>   7. Press the Next button.
>
> WCE MFC AppWizard (exe) - Step 2 of 4
>   will appear as seen in Figure 5. There
>   are several options on this page. You
>   can add support for Windows Sockets,
>   ActiveX Controls, Windows Help, and
>   Printing if your target supports
>   Windows CE 2.1. You also can choose
>   the type of command bar that you wish
>   to support. For this exercise we will
>   accept the defaults.
>   8. Accept the defaults.
>   9. Press the Next button.
>
> WCE MFC AppWizard (exe) - Step 3 of 4
>   will appear as seen in Figure 6. You
>   can choose to include generated
>   comments, an option that I highly
>   recommend. There is no such thing as
>   too much documentation. There is also
>   an option to link dynamically or
>   statically with the MFC Library.
>   Accept the defaults.
>   10. Accept the defaults.
>   11. Press the Next button.
>
> WCE MFC AppWizard (exe) - Step 4 of 4
>   will appear as seen in Figure 7. This
>   page gives you an opportunity to set
>   the base class for the view. It also
>   gives you an opportunity to set your
>   file names. Accept the defaults.
>   12. Accept the defaults.
>   13. Press the Finish button.
>
> The New Project Information dialog
>   will appear as seen in Figure 8. Just
>   like all Visual Studio AppWizards the
>   wizards give you a final chance to
>   look over your choices.
>   14. Press the Ok Button.
>   15. Select Build menu and choose the Rebuild All item.
>
> When the application is completed
>   building, you are ready to go on to
>   the next section.

---

Also see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa924098.aspx).